# Adding a calculated due date through an Access query

Tags: ms-access

I'm very new with Microsoft Access and am in the process of setting up a simple database to track due dates on invoices. I have two tables set up, one of all the open invoices sent to our customers along with the billed date which will be input on a 2 - 3 times / week basis, and the other is a table of the customer pay terms by days. The join is as follows:

```
SELECT [Customer Info].CUSTOMER, [Schedule 40].Date, [Schedule 40].[Invoice Number], 
       [Schedule 40].[Open A/R Amount], [Schedule 40].[Currency From], 
       [Customer Info].[PAY TERMS] 
FROM [Customer Info] 
INNER JOIN [Schedule 40] 
ON [Customer Info].[CUSTOMER] = [Schedule 40].[Customer];
```

The customer info table is made up of two columns on the join, one which outlines the various customers we've invoiced and acts as the key to the schedule 40 table, and the other which is pay terms. The pay terms values range from 1, 4, 5, 15, and 45 days. My end goal is run a query to combine the pay terms with the open invoices and add the pay terms to the billed date to determine the due date and highlight past due invoices. I'm not entirely sure how to create a query within access to add the pay term days to the billed date and have that output the due date for the invoices, any help would be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: It would be better if you provided the schema (with code to recreate) instead of describing the tables, and also your attempt at the query. Should be something like a join, but that depends on how your schema is made.

Comment: Hi Peeyush,

Appreciate the response, below is the SQL from the join:

SELECT [Customer Info].CUSTOMER, [Schedule 40].Date, [Schedule 40].[Invoice Number], [Schedule 40].[Open A/R Amount], [Schedule 40].[Currency From], [Customer Info].[PAY TERMS]
FROM [Customer Info] INNER JOIN [Schedule 40] ON [Customer Info].[CUSTOMER] = [Schedule 40].[Customer];

My challenge is having the query insert a column on the output which would be the the date + pay terms as I'm not sure how to add that in the query wizard. Let me know if any additional information is needed.

Comment: Can you put the code in the question....so you already have the output with that query, all you want is to use the output for each invoice number, you want to use `Schedule40.Date` and `Pay terms` to determine the final date and insert it into the Schedule 40 table? What are the values for the payterm column?

Comment: Ideally the due date would be included on the output of the query if possible. The schedule 40 table will be deleted and replaced with a new input 2 - 3 times / week. The pay terms column values vary to something like: Customer 1, 45; Customer 2, 4; Customer 3, 15; etc.

Comment: Pay term column are 45 days? Please can you put all this information in the question. Do you understand that the more clear your question is the better and faster you will get a response.

Comment: Also look at the date add function in access: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_msaccess_dateadd.asp

Comment: Also here is an example of inserting into a table using a select statement: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/insert-into-statement-microsoft-access-sql

Comment: I apologize for any confusion, I realize what may seem to make sense to me on this post may not to others. The date add function is helpful and seems to be in the direction of what I am looking for, however I would need to add a variable number based off the customer specific pay terms vs a static number as defined in the guide.

Comment: Please look at the last example it shows that you can take a column name instead of a fixed number.

Comment: This might need VBA solution. Have you done a search on topic "Access database invoice aging"? Here's one for a start https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/access-cookbook/0596000847/ch01s09.html